# Angular tabset tab order not maintained

Tags: angular

I have three tabs. I hide the middle tab with some condition. The problem is when the condition is true, the tab moves after the third tab

```
<tabset class="span-heading-padding">
    <tab>
       <span class="header-text">First</span>
    </tab>
    <tab *ngIf=ShowThisTab>
       <span class="header-text">Second</span>
    </tab>
    <tab>
       <span class="header-text">Third</span>
    </tab>
</tabset
```

This show tabs in correct order - First, Second, Third

When ShowThisTab is false second tab is not shown - First, Third

When ShowThisTab becomes true, the second tab is in the wrong position - First, Third, Second

Anyone has faced this?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue using codesandbox or stackblitz?

Comment: @user2837961 If you want to use `ngIF` you can check my answer :-)

Comment: Add `*ngIf=true` in each tab has to be always visible.

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace `ngIf` with

```
[style.display]="ShowThisTab? 'none': 'block'"
```

Edit for yours example

```
<tab [style.display]="ShowThisTab ? 'block': 'none'">
       <span class="header-text">Second</span>
</tab>
```

Comment: This does not hide the tab

Comment: Strangely it does not hide the tab at all. ngIf does

Comment: Could be that the style already defined and in-line style not apply

Comment: I think (not sure) the problem is that all tabs are rendered before my conditional tab

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by using a directive shown in this post(right at the bottom)

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/823

Comment: While your answer may be correct, linking to a post is not the correct way to answer a question. There is no way to know if that link will still be available a year from now, or if the content of a link may change an no longer answer the question.  Linking to the answer is fine - but you should also answer the question here so if the link does change the answer is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my link for `*ngIF`.

Here is my HTML=>

```
<button (click)="myChange()">>Hide/Show</button>
<tabset>
  <tab  header="First" >
     <ng-template tabContent><span class="header-text">First</span></ng-template>
  </tab>
  <tab *ngIf="ShowThisTab" header="Second">
    <ng-template tabContent><span class="header-text">Second</span></ng-template>
  </tab>
   <tab header="Third">
    <ng-template tabContent><span class="header-text">Third</span></ng-template>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  ShowThisTab:boolean=false;
  myChange(){
    this.ShowThisTab=!this.ShowThisTab;
  }
}
```

**Note:** Demo Link in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tabset-component-5p8gnt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: I can see the demo working. But in my case the tab is appended at the end

Comment: @user2837961 Ok Let me check

Answer (score 0):

You can use **kendo-tabstrip** from Kendo UI Angular instead of **tabset**. It will fix the problem.

```
  <kendo-tabstrip>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'One'" [selected]="true"></kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Two'" *ngIf="ShowThisTab"></kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Three'"></kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Four'"></kendo-tabstrip-tab>
  </kendo-tabstrip>
```

**Demo Link:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dq1sjf?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to resolve this issue.

The tabset has an array of tabs that you can sort by some attribute, for example ID

**1 - Define in your HTML code an ID for each tab to be sorted and a reference to your tabset**

```
<button (click)="myChange()">>Hide/Show</button>
<tabset #tabset>
  <tab header="First" id="tab01">
     <ng-template tabContent><span class="header-text">First</span></ng-template>
  </tab>
  <tab *ngIf="ShowThisTab" header="Second" id="tab02">
    <ng-template tabContent><span class="header-text">Second</span></ng-template>
  </tab>
   <tab header="Third" id="tab03">
    <ng-template tabContent><span class="header-text">Third</span></ng-template>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

**2 - Use @ViewChild to retrieve the reference in your Typescript code**

```
@ViewChild('tabset') tabset: TabsetComponent;
```

**3 - In AfterViewInit() or at some point in your code where you can guarantee that your status will change, sort by IDs**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.tabset.tabs.sort((first:TabDirective, second:TabDirective) => {  return (first.id > second.id) ?  1 :  -1 } );
}
```